# i don't know why this api url 404 (Coinranking API)

Tags: api, rest, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coin/Qwsogvtv82FCd/history/24h
i use this url GET type with redux-query why is not working??
this is my code

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
  "X-RapidAPI-Host": "coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com",
  "X-RapidAPI-Key": "6b9109d854mshae17bc83f3a405ap166111jsna0c3fc584445"
};

const baseUrl = "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com";

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });
export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "cryptoApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptos: builder.query({
      query: (count) => createRequest(`/coins?limit=${count}`)
    }),
    getCryptoDetail: builder.query({
      query: (coinId) => createRequest(`/coin/${coinId}`)
    }),
    getCryptoHistory: builder.query({
      query: ({ coinId, timePeriod }) =>
        createRequest(`/coin/${coinId}/history/${timePeriod}`)
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetCryptosQuery,
  useGetCryptoDetailQuery,
  useGetCryptoHistoryQuery
} = cryptoApi;


this is my chart.jsx code

import { Chart as ChartJS, registerables } from "chart.js";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Col, Row, Typography } from "antd";
const { Title } = Typography;

ChartJS.register(...registerables);

const CoinChart = ({ coinHistory, currentPrice, coinName }) => {
  const coinPrice = [];
  const coinTimestamp = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < coinHistory?.data?.history?.length; i += 1) {
    coinPrice.push(coinHistory.data.history[i].price);
    coinTimestamp.push(
      new Date(coinHistory.data.history[i].timestamp).toLocaleDateString()
    );
  }
  const data = {
    labels: coinTimestamp,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Price USD",
        data: coinPrice,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#0071bd",
        borderColor: "#0071bd"
      }
    ]
  };
  var options = {
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 0
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Row className="chart-header">
        <Title level={2} className="chart-title">
          {coinName} Chart
        </Title>
        <Col className="price">
          <Title level={4} className="price-change">
            {coinHistory?.data?.change}%
          </Title>
          <Title level={4} className="current-price">
            Current {coinName} Price: {currentPrice} $
          </Title>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CoinChart;
```

i want to print coin chart in my page but it doesn't work
so i search the error develop tool says this url 404
i don't know why this url not working
i'm testing this url in rapidapi.com it's working!!
but my website not working
plz help me!!

Comment: This request 404s for me as well in a http client (outside the browser). Don't think this is related to react/redux at all, you should try to make a successful request via http client before implementing this in your frontend.

Comment: same site url is working my website If so, isn't there no problem with my request?

Comment: Compare the requests (headers, params, payload, etc.) and figure out where they differ.